# $n+1$ people roll fair dice labelled "$1, 2, \cdots, n$". Person A rolls the strictly highest die roll. What is the expected value?

Tags: probability, asymptotics, expected-value

So I have the following question:

> $21$ people roll isosahedral dice labelled "$1, 2, \cdots, n$" (including person A). Person A rolls the strictly highest die roll. What is the expected value of their roll?

So I quickly found out, using Wolfram Alpha, that it was around $19.5$. However, this made me wonder about what the expected value was for $n$ sided dice and $n+1$ people.

The chance that Person A rolls $i+1$ is $\frac1n$, and the chance that everyone else gets lower than person A is $\left(\frac in\right)^n$. Thus, the expected value of Person A's roll is $$\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}(i+1)\frac1n\left(\frac in\right)^n}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}\frac1n\left(\frac in\right)^n}=\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}(i+1)i^n}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}=\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^{n+1}+\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}=\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^{n+1}}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}+\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}=\frac{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^{n+1}}{\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}i^n}+1$$

I decided to have a look at what this expression approached, and it seems that the expected value converges towards $n-c$, where $c$ is a constant roughly equal to $0.6$. However, I would like to know:

- How to show that the coefficient of $n$ in the asymptotic expansion of the expected value is $1$
- What exactly the constant after $n$ is asymptotic expansion of the expected value
- If possible, more terms in the asymptotic expansion of the expected value.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Okay, but how do I get from there to an asymptotic expression? The formula seems horrible to manipulate, and I have no clue how big $B_n$ is.

Comment: For the asymptotic analysis, you have to figure out what the dominant term is, and divide numerator and denominator by it.  (I don't say this will be easy.)  For the Bernoulli numbers a great deal is known.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Bernoulli_numbers_and_the_Riemann_zeta_function) you will find an asymptotic formula for $|B_{2n}|$  Recall $B_{2n+1}=0$ for $n>0$.  Because the Bernoulli numbers appear, it may be necessary to treat the cases $n$ odd and $n$ even separately.